# I want to count the number of pizzas of one particular type in SPARQL with the pizza ontology, but it fails

Tags: sparql, jena, owl

I am a beginner in SPARQL. I am using the [pizza ontology](https://github.com/owlcs/pizza-ontology) and I am trying to write a SPARQL query to get the number of pizzas of a particular topping.

If I have this query:

```
prefix pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
select ?pizza 
where {?pizza a owl:Class ;
                      rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction.
                     ?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;
                            owl:someValuesFrom pizza:PeperoniSausageTopping
}
```

I have the following result (using Jena):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| pizza                                                          |
==================================================================
| <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#FourSeasons> |
| <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#American>    |
| <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#AmericanHot> |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I wanted to return the number of pizzas for the query (here 3), and not the list of pizzas, so I wrote this query:

```
prefix pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
select (sum(?pizza))
where {?pizza a owl:Class ;
                      rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction.
                     ?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;
                            owl:someValuesFrom pizza:PeperoniSausageTopping
}
```

But I have an exception, the query is incorrect, what did I do wrong?
The Exception I have with Jena is:

```
org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 5, column 20.
Was expecting one of:
    "not" ...
    "as" ...
    "in" ...
    <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
    "=" ...
    "!=" ...
    ">" ...
    "<" ...
    "<=" ...
    ">=" ...
    "||" ...
    "&&" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
```

Comment: `select (count(?pizza) as ?count)` or `select (count(distinct ?pizza) as ?count)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works like a charm!!